# what are the possible locations of persistence.xml file in a web archive in jpa and how to specify that location for getting EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: jpa

```
**EntityManagerFactory factory=Persistence.getEnityManagerFactory(???);**
```

In specification they are explained in the context of EJBs.But i am not understanding the actual possible locations of persistence.xml in a web archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The persistence.xml must always be in the META-INF directory on the classpath.  Normally it will be inside a jar that is on the classpath, such as a jar in /WEB-INF/lib/ in your war file.

Comment: Thank you very much... now i got clarity, So the runtime will search for persistence.xml on META-INF/persistence.xml. This META-INF/persistence.xml will be added to classpath when it is in classes folder or when it is inside a jar on lib